# rss2json won't get the newest feed update that i have put in my feed.xml file

Tags: javascript, html, xml, rss

I wan't to be able to update my web page content by rss feed. 
I have use rss2json to get the text out of the feed to the page.

I have created feed.xml file and when updating that the contents of the web page will be updated. When i refresh the page once everything works, but when I add something to the xml file and refresh the page stays the same. And when i look the xml file on the server it has the updated information, but it doesn't just load up somehow. But if I change the xml filename example to feed1.xml and update the html point to that. Everything works and the new feed information shows up.

Is there some kind of cache somewhere? I have tried deleting the browser history but it has no effect. what else could it be?

Answer (score 3):

rss2json responses seem to be cached by a CDN. add a query parameter ?t=time_stamp
replace time_stamp with a unix timestamp.
The CDN won't find the cached url, because it's always new, and you should get the latest data always